# Proving after some minutes nobody will change her marker

Tags: combinatorics, induction

**$2017$ people are sitting around a table each of them has a blue and a red marker but each of them like one of the colors of markers. in each moment all people put their favorite marker on the table at the same time. if the favorite color of somebody is not as like as two people who are sitting next to him or her that person will change the marker. prove after some minutes nobody will change her marker.**

I apologize because not clarifying.@gandalf61 nicely mentioned rules, therefore, I just copy them:

1)In the initial state, everyone puts down their red or blue marker at random.

2)In each round of changes, a person will only change their displayed marker if the markers displayed by the people on either side of them are both the opposite color to their own displayed marker. Thus if a person displays Blue they will only change to Red if both people on either side of them are displaying Red. In all other cases, they continue to display Blue.

3)All changes in each round take place simultaneously.

I tried to solve it using induction. I assumed if there are $n$ person sitting around the table which $n$ is odd after some minutes they won't change any marker and I tried to prove it is also true for $n+2$ people but I cant prove $n+2$ person can change their marker in a way that they achieve the last situation of $n$ people which there won't be any more changes (if we don't care about two new people)

*please share your ideas in comments and write an answer even if your solution isn't complete. thanks!*

Comment: What does "favourite colour of anybody is  *not as like* as two people who are sitting next to him/her" mean? Also, when you say : "that person will change the marker and *other* will not change the marker", do you mean by "other", the two people sitting next to this person, or everybody else?

Comment: consider three people who are sitting next to each other if the favorite color of the middle person is opposite of two other people the middle person will change the marker

Comment: I have edited it is more clear now

Comment: Thank you for the edit.

Comment: When you say : "the middle person will change the marker", that means he will also change his favourite color, since he must hold a marker of his "favourite color" in his hand? I wish to clarify a few more things in case I do not write a wrong answer.

Comment: there is no difference between favorite color and the marker which is on the table actually every person puts her favorite marker which has his favorite color

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг is it clear for you now?

Comment: That doesn't make sense. I can replace the red marker with a blue one **and** keep the red color to be my favourite. My favourite color is _mine_, not the actual color of the marker currently on the table. Can you possibly drop the 'favourite' from the problem and describe it from outside with 'every person puts one of their marker', 'a person exchanges the marker' etc. without mentioning their personal, inner color preferences?

Comment: sorry I have to go some where I will edit it 2 hours later if anyone can edit it please do it

Comment: Please clarify the rules. Suppose I put a red marker and one of my neighbor puts red, too, and the other one puts blue. Should I change my marker (because it differs from one of neighboring markers, so 'is not as like as two people who are sitting next to me')?

Comment: I will wait till you clarify. Question seems interesting even half specified.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, here is my interpretation of the rules:

1. In the initial state, everyone puts down their red or blue marker at random (I think the "favourite colour" thing is irrelevant and confusing).
2. In each round of changes, a person will only change their displayed marker if the markers displayed by the people on either side of them are *both* the opposite colour to their own displayed marker. Thus if a person displays Blue they will only change to Red if both people on either side of them are displaying Red. In all other cases they continue to display Blue.
3. All changes in each round take place simultaneously.

Then we can draw the following conclusions:

1. A person who is part of a contiguous block of 2 or more markers which are all the same colour will never change their marker. Let's call a block of 2 or more markers all the same colour a "static block" and a block of 1 a "singleton".
2. A sequence of singletons that is bordered on each side by a static block can only get shorter. For example

...BBRBRBRR... -> ...BBBRBRRR... -> ....BBBBRRRR...

3. So the number of singletons gets smaller in each round of changes until it reaches zero *unless* there are no static blocks around the table in the initial state. For example, in a table of 4 we could start with BRBR, which then changes to RBRB, which then changes back to BRBR etc.

The final step (not difficult !) is to show that there must be at least one static block in the initial state of a table with 2017 people.

Comment: @mathenthusiastic Please recall your _'2017 people are sitting **around a table**'_...

Comment: @CiaPan sorry what do you mean by recall (not native speaker)

Comment: @mathenthusiastic By 'recall' I meant opposite to 'forget': it's an important assumption the people are sitting **around the table**, and you seemed to forget it. This assumption implies the sequence RBRB...RBR actually makes a 'static block', as gandalf61 calls it, because in the **circular arangement** around the table the starting R and the ending R are neighbours; they are next to each other.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize in advance for my messy notation.

Ah, I understand the question. Consider a coloring the vertices of $C_n$ red and blue and call this coloring $\chi_0$. We now construct a sequence of colorings in the folowing way: at time $i$, for any $v\in C_n$, if $\chi_{i-1}(v-1)=\chi_{i-1}(v+1)=red$ yet $\chi_{i-1}(v)=blue$ (all addition is modulo $n$), then $\chi_i(v)=red$. Similarly, if $\chi_{i-1}(v-1)=\chi_{i-1}(v+1)=blue$ yet $\chi_{i-1}(v)=red$, then $\chi_i(v)=blue$. In other words, a vertex will flip it's color if it disagrees with both of its neighbors. Now, what you'd like to prove is that no matter what $\chi_0$ was, there is some time $t$ for which $\chi_t=\chi_{t+1}$.

Now, this is false in general, since if $n$ is even, $\chi_0$ could alternate around the cycle and the process won't ever stop. But the key is that $n$ is odd. In particular, there must be some vertex $v$ with $\chi_0(v)=\chi_0(v+1)$.

Now for just a bit of terminology: A cyclic interval $I\subseteq[n]$ is said to be

1. **monochromatic** if all vertices in $I$ have the same color,
2. **non-trivial** if $|I|\geq 2$,
3. **maximal under a coloring $\chi$** if $I=\{v,v+1,\dots,v+r\}$ where $\chi(v)\neq\chi(v-1)$ and also $\chi(v+r)\neq\chi(v+r+1)$.

Now, let $\mathcal{I}_t$ denote the collection of all monochromatic, non-trivial, maximal intervals under $\chi_t$ and let $N_t=\sum_{I\in\mathcal{I}_t}|I|$. Notice that every pair of intervals in $\mathcal{I}_t$ are disjoint. Furthermore, if $v\in I$ for some $I\in\mathcal{I}_t$, then $v$'s color will never change after this step. In particular, no interval in $\mathcal{I}_t$ can every shrink when building $\mathcal{I}_{t+1}$. It suffices to show that there is some $t$ for which $N_t=n$; if this is the case, then then $\chi_t=\chi_{t+1}$, so the coloring has stabilized.

Now, suppose that $N_t\neq n$; I claim that $N_{t+1}\geq N_t+1$. If this is the case then we're done. By the earlier remark, we know that $\mathcal{I}_0\neq\varnothing$, so we also know that $\mathcal{I}_t\neq\varnothing$ and since $N_t\neq n$, there is some $v\in[n]$ which is not in any interval in $\mathcal{I}_t$. We can, in fact, find such a $v$ and an interval $I\in\mathcal{I}_t$ so that $v-1\in I$. Also, wlog, we may assume $\chi_t(v)=red$ and $\chi_{t}(v-1)=blue$. Now, consider $v+1$. We can't have $\chi_t(v+1)=red$ or else $v$ would be contained in some interval in $\mathcal{I}_t$. Thus, $\chi_t(v+1)=blue$, so we know that $\chi_{t+1}(v)=blue$. Since $\chi_{t+1}(v-1)=\chi_t(v-1)=blue$, we know that $v$ is part of an interval in $\mathcal{I}_{t+1}$, so we must have $N_{t+1}\geq N_t+1$.